# Create a datatype in a table that is a list of references to other table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes

I need to create a database with the following idea:

**Preparing questions:**

The teacher builds a pool of questions for use in the exams. The question includes a text and four answers. One of the answers is marked as the correct answer.

Each question in the database matches one subject, and one or more courses on the subject.
Each question has a number that identifies it uniquely, 5 digits.
For example: No. 02105: Subject: Mathematics (02), question number (105).

**Preparation for exams:**

The teacher builds exams that include questions from the database. Each exam has a number that identifies it in some way
Unique, 6 digits.
For example: 020301: Subject: Mathematics (02), Course: Algebra (03), Exam Number (01)

The duration of the assigned solution (in minutes) and the number of points per question is defined.

I created those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `idcourse` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `courseName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcourse`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `idsubject` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `subjectName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsubject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `questionText` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjetID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `questionNum.` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjetID`,`questionNum.`),
  CONSTRAINT `idsubject` FOREIGN KEY (`subjetID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`idsubject`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

--

```
CREATE TABLE `exam` (
  `subjectID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `courseID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `examNumber` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pointsPerQuestionl` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjectID`,`courseID`,`examNumber`),
  KEY `idCourse_idx` (`courseID`),
  CONSTRAINT `idCo` FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`) REFERENCES `course` (`idcourse`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idSu` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`idsubject`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**About the tables, I not sure if I had created them correctly**

In exam I have number of questions.
For each question I need to define number of points.

How do I make this on my table relation?

Thanks.

Comment: this looks like REALLY simple sql work... Like homework... you join on subject ID.

Comment: I created these tables in mySQL.
How do I create a Datatype in a subject table so that it will be a list of questions?

Comment: Why would you want to? The subject id is a foreign key, just join and select. Group concat if you need to

Comment: Thanks, I understood the usage of join.

 how can I define for each question in the exam the number of points?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
select a.subjectname,b.questionText
from
subject a
left join
question b
on a.idsubject = b.subjectid;
```

You can proceed in the similar for the second problem.